# AddCookies in browserContext in Playwright Java

Tags: playwright-java

I am trying to add cookies in playwright Java using browser Context in the playwright
below is the code i am using

```
 getURL(URL);
        List<Cookie> ls = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
        ls.add(new Cookie("JESSIONID",val));
        context.addCookies(ls);
        reload();
```

now while trying to run, it
it is giving me below error:

```
com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='Cookie should have a URL or a domain/path pair
  name='Error
  stack='Error: Cookie should have a url or a domain/path pair
```

Even i also did this:

```
ls.add(new Cookie("JESSIONID",val,"path"));
```

This giving me compilation error saying you cannot add extra parameter in cookie

I am not able to add path in the cookie although it is the optional parameter
Can you guys please help how can i add path in the cookie constructors ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Cookie> ls = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JESSIONID",val);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setDomain("DOMAIN");
ls.add(cookie);
context.addCookies(ls);
reload();
```